# Why does windows console program run in new command prompt?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, console

Recently, I was charged with maintaining a windows console application written in C++ in Visual Studio. I can run it from the console by just typing the program name, for eg. program_name.exe . However, when I run it in windows 10, it opens a new command prompt window and prints its output to that window. However, in other versions of windows, like windows server 2019 it does not open a new command prompt window but prints its output in the same command prompt window from where it was launched. I don't want it to open a new command prompt. I want it to give its output in the same command prompt where it was launched. How do I fix this issue in windows 10?

EDIT: Additional info: This application is a .exe which also invokes a .dll library.

Comment: What is the `/SUBSYSTEM` set to in the linker options? (I'm assuming this is a VS project).

Comment: @M.A : It is /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE

Comment: Being run in a sandbox by your antivirus scanner?

Comment: The only time I have seen this happen was what @AlanBirtles said a sandbox from an AV

Comment: @AlanBirtles : Is my antivirus doing this automatically? Why?

Comment: @user15740 do you understand the concept of a ["sandbox"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_(software_development))?  If the AV really is the one doing this, then it is isolating the new process from the rest of the system to minimize the risk of the process being able to do any damage if it happens to run any ill-formed or malicious code.

Comment: Possibly related: [Control whether Windows command line commands run in new window](https://superuser.com/questions/244392/) Are you *sure* the program in question is not simply creating its own window?

Comment: @RemyLebeau : No the program is not creating its own window as on other systems it generates its output in the same command prompt window.